# Severe: org.hibernate.TransactionException: nested transactions not supported

Tags: hibernate

I am doing this tutorial on Hibernate: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html

My issue:
After I am done with the instructions and run the project, I get Hibernate Error: "Severe:   org.hibernate.TransactionException: nested transactions not supported"

I tried "tx.commit();" to close the transaction but that didn't change anything.

question: why did it work when the tutorial people wrote the instructions but not working now? and how to get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

change

```
    public FilmHelper() {
        this.session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    }
```

to

```
    public FilmHelper() {
        this.session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    }
```

Reason:
Tutorial uses Hibernate 3 and now I am using Hibernate 4. 
In Hibernate3, once transaction is complete it is closed and the same session is allowed to open a new transaction w/ NoProblem. 
In Hibernate4, once transaction is complete it is still open. if a developer close it then the session close with it. developer has to manually open a new session.

If anyone knows more about Hibernate and like to add to this, please comment below me.